# Entering data from a userform to a table using first blank cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba, userform

*I want to enter data from my userform to a table. I foolishly thought I could do this the same way as when I entered it into a range.* ***EDIT-my script actually does work to add the info to a table. I was mistaken.*** I also need to start my entry at the first blank cell in column A, and right now I have it set to the first blank row. I appreciate any help! Here is the code I have currently:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub cmdfir_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lPart As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PQR data")

'find  first empty row in database
''lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
''  .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'revised code to avoid problems with
'Excel lists and tables in newer versions
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'copy the data to the database
With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cbodatecoated.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cbodatepacked.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cboline.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cbocustomer.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cbopartnumber.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cbopartrev.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.cbopowdernumberused.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.cbopowderlotnumber.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.cboboxnumbers.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.cbocont.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.cbolight.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.cboheavy.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.cbofisheye.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 14).Value = Me.cboseeds.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 15).Value = Me.cbodirt.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 16).Value = Me.cboorangepeel.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 17).Value = Me.cbochemicals.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 18).Value = Me.cbospits.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 19).Value = Me.cboyarn.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 20).Value = Me.cboscratch.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 21).Value = Me.cbodrops.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 22).Value = Me.cbotabs.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 23).Value = Me.cboother.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 25).Value = Me.cbometal.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 26).Value = Me.cbopackedgood.Value
  
End With

'clear the data

Me.cboline.Value = 1
Me.cbocustomer.Value = "Gentex"
Me.cbopartnumber.Value = "350-0010-001"
Me.cbopartrev.Value = ""
Me.cbopowdernumberused.Value = "PY"
Me.cbopowderlotnumber.Value = ""
Me.cboboxnumbers.Value = ""
Me.cbocont.Value = ""
Me.cbolight.Value = ""
Me.cboheavy.Value = ""
Me.cbofisheye.Value = ""
Me.cboseeds.Value = ""
Me.cbodirt.Value = ""
Me.cboorangepeel.Value = ""
Me.cbochemicals.Value = ""
Me.cbospits.Value = ""
Me.cboyarn.Value = ""
Me.cboscratch.Value = ""
Me.cbodrops.Value = ""
Me.cbotabs.Value = ""
Me.cboother.Value = ""
Me.cbometal.Value = ""
Me.cbopackedgood.Value = ""
Me.cboline.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: "enter data from my userform to a table" means add a row to an existing listobject/table and not just a regular range?

Comment: So after reading your comment I went back and re-ran the script in the table I now cleared out. It definitely is adding to the table. My only issue now is getting it to start the entry at the first blank cell in a column, instead of looking for a blank row to start in. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: `lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row +1` for example